# OData client not rehydrating using $expand

Tags: odata

I've been using OData for a while now and am finding it a fantastic tool for setting up my server. Today I've come across something I haven't seen before and it's absolutely confounding me.

I'm using .Expand on the client to request a tree of data for a report when it's fetched. I've used the exact query in a prototype and it worked perfectly (ie fully hydrated). When I use Fiddler to send the query the response packet is perfect and includes all of the data I'm looking for.

The problem is that none of the expanded properties have been hydrated by the client (with a service reference completely up-to-date with the current service). In order to try and work out what's going on I've narrowed the scope right back to a single property and it's still not working.

```
var report = (serviceContext.Reports.Expand("ReportAreas").Where(r=>r.ReportID==reportID)).SingleOrDefault();
```

gives me the report but ReportAreas contains 0 items.  If I then try:

```
serviceContext.LoadProperty(report,"ReportAreas");
```

then ReportAreas contains 20 or so items.

It's driving me absolutely crazy because Expand is working for a different object tree (different query but same functional code) without any issues at all. Does anyone have suggestions as to how I can work out what on earth is going on here???

**Update:**

Some new information on this one today which is possibly wierder and suggests to me a bug in the OData client. I've discovered that only a subset of the Report objects come back without the expanded properties being populated. MOST of the reports in the database are perfectly fine. ie If I request all Reports with ReportAreas expanded (instead of refining to a single reportID) about 80-90% have a non-zero count for ReportAreas where the remainder have 0.

When a report comes back without any of the properties populated (null or 0 count) the actual property objects are being instantiated AND their properties are being set (from breakpoints in the Reference.cs file for the service reference) so, for example the ReportID, PropertyAreaID and History values belonging to ReportArea objects are set 16 times during the query resolution but the ReportAreas list has a count of 0 when it is requested. When I use _service.LoadProperty it returns 16 ReportAreas.

It smells to me of a reference mismatch in the Expand query but it is too consistent to be a simple problem. Reports that work ALWAYS work and Reports that don't work NEVER work. Really hoping someone can help me pinpoint this so I can move on to some useful coding...

Comment: Can you try Fiddler and see what query (URL) is send to the server and if the response contains the expanded data.

Comment: As per paragraph 2 "When I use Fiddler to send the query the response packet is perfect (ie contains all of the expanded data)"

Comment: I understand that when you send the request manually from Fiddler it works. I was asking if you could use Fiddler to see the request sent by the client application, especially the URL asked for and the response.

Comment: Ahhh... Don't have time to check now. I'll get onto it first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: Ok, as I suspected the request and response appear to be perfectly formed. The only thing that's not happening is the objects appearing as part of the object graph. I can populate every one of the properties with service.Property( , ) but it's taking about 30 seconds.

Comment: The responses to each of the Property requests has the same data (aside from some wrapping differences)

Comment: Is there any way to hook into the rehydration process???

Comment: There's no hook like that. It should work. Can you please share the definition of the Report class (specifically the ReportAreas property)?

Comment: I just tried the demo service on http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc. Just Add Service Reference to it and then write query: var category = ctx.Categories.Expand("Products").Where(c => c.ID == 1).SingleOrDefault(); It correctly loads the products as expected.

Comment: I've seen the client library work in many instances. In the application I'm writing it works fine with two other classes. It's just that for the Report object it is failing. As I mentioned the prototype code (which is fundamentally the same, based on the same DB) actually worked fine for the report as well. It's confusing the hell out of me why this isn't working. I'll try and post the class structures, messages, etc later today.

Comment: I'm working on a separate prototype project and just loaded the report with expand with no problems. I've done Update Service Reference a number of times but I suspect removing the reference and adding it again will probably fix my problem... I'll post an answer if that fixes it.

Comment: Sign... spoke too soon. Looks like there's some level of caching in the service reference as it's only fully populating on a second call AFTER the properties have been individually populated. I'll get the class and data structs up later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem (at least until I understand it better) is to set

```
serviceContext.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
```

I've been told this relates to the client not rehydrating links if they're already being tracked. I'll update this answer if I find out more/understand the problem better.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602811(v=vs.103).aspx
"By default, the client only materializes an entry in the response feed into an object for entities that are not already being tracked by the DataServiceContext. This means that changes to objects already in the cache are not overwritten. This behavior is controlled by specifying a MergeOption value for queries and load operations."

Comment: This has no bearing on the initial problem. Even if the particular objects had previously been loaded by the context (which they hadn't) I would still expect them to appear in the ReportAreas collection. Otherwise the referential integrity of the database gets thrown completely off because I might try and re-insert objects that are already on the server due to those objects 'not being present' on the client when I load from the server.